# What is the best way to calculate the standard deviation

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, statistics

I have a 50x22 matrix/vector, and i need to calculate the standard deviation from each column, precisely it looks like this.[image]

For instance, the first column: [245, 244, 247, 243... 239], then second column [115, 106, 99...149] and on...

I did try calculating it using a calculator, i guess it wasn't a good idea, it took me a while, but i figured numpy could help me.

The thing is, what i tried was:

```
std_vec = np.std(img_feats[0])
```

The output was all wrong, when i compared to the firt column that i obtained using the calculator.

This is the actual output, since the image picture does not look good.

```
[247, 111, 162, 47, 39, 42, 47, 42, 204, 215, 50, 57, 196, 209, 199, 184, 219, 201, 204, 218]
[247, 108, 160, 47, 39, 44, 48, 44, 204, 213, 51, 60, 198, 205, 201, 184, 219, 201, 202, 216]
[245, 96, 160, 46, 38, 43, 44, 40, 195, 213, 51, 57, 199, 202, 204, 187, 222, 201, 202, 207]
[245, 102, 161, 46, 40, 41, 46, 40, 198, 213, 51, 55, 199, 210, 202, 187, 220, 202, 204, 210]
[246, 104, 160, 49, 38, 41, 46, 41, 198, 214, 52, 55, 199, 210, 204, 185, 220, 204, 204, 208]
[246, 107, 160, 47, 40, 40, 46, 40, 196, 213, 51, 57, 199, 207, 201, 185, 220, 202, 205, 208]
[246, 116, 161, 48, 40, 43, 45, 41, 201, 213, 51, 58, 201, 201, 204, 184, 219, 204, 205, 210]
[246, 123, 169, 48, 40, 42, 46, 43, 202, 213, 51, 64, 199, 198, 201, 189, 217, 199, 207, 216]
[246, 123, 167, 48, 40, 40, 45, 43, 204, 213, 51, 67, 198, 199, 202, 187, 219, 199, 207, 214]
[246, 122, 167, 48, 40, 43, 46, 43, 202, 213, 51, 64, 199, 197, 200, 185, 219, 199, 208, 213]
[245, 115, 165, 47, 38, 43, 44, 43, 199, 213, 51, 58, 199, 191, 203, 187, 217, 194, 206, 208]
[244, 106, 162, 47, 40, 40, 43, 40, 194, 214, 49, 58, 199, 188, 205, 191, 216, 199, 203, 208]
[247, 99, 160, 46, 42, 40, 46, 42, 201, 213, 51, 55, 198, 204, 201, 185, 220, 199, 202, 216]
[243, 98, 161, 47, 41, 43, 43, 40, 193, 214, 50, 58, 199, 191, 207, 190, 214, 197, 205, 207]
[242, 96, 159, 46, 40, 41, 44, 43, 188, 214, 50, 56, 200, 197, 208, 190, 214, 197, 205, 205]
[243, 99, 164, 47, 40, 41, 44, 41, 189, 213, 49, 55, 201, 198, 208, 192, 215, 198, 204, 205]
[245, 105, 166, 49, 40, 41, 44, 40, 193, 215, 49, 56, 199, 202, 207, 192, 218, 201, 207, 208]
[246, 112, 167, 46, 40, 44, 44, 43, 195, 211, 50, 60, 198, 204, 205, 190, 218, 201, 205, 210]
[245, 112, 166, 47, 40, 43, 44, 43, 199, 214, 49, 59, 202, 205, 205, 188, 219, 201, 208, 210]
[245, 112, 165, 47, 39, 44, 46, 43, 197, 213, 50, 58, 200, 204, 205, 188, 219, 202, 208, 211]
[245, 111, 167, 45, 42, 42, 42, 41, 199, 213, 50, 59, 200, 203, 210, 187, 219, 200, 208, 211]
[245, 115, 167, 48, 41, 42, 44, 42, 199, 212, 51, 62, 200, 205, 206, 187, 219, 202, 209, 211]
[244, 122, 168, 47, 42, 41, 45, 41, 199, 212, 51, 63, 200, 203, 206, 185, 219, 200, 208, 212]
[247, 99, 160, 45, 40, 42, 48, 43, 200, 211, 51, 55, 197, 202, 199, 184, 220, 199, 204, 214]
[244, 121, 168, 50, 39, 42, 43, 40, 202, 211, 50, 63, 200, 199, 208, 183, 220, 203, 208, 212]
[245, 121, 167, 50, 40, 42, 43, 40, 200, 212, 50, 63, 202, 197, 208, 186, 220, 203, 208, 215]
[245, 119, 165, 48, 40, 42, 45, 42, 199, 212, 50, 62, 202, 194, 206, 186, 218, 200, 209, 211]
[245, 124, 165, 47, 37, 42, 45, 40, 202, 211, 50, 63, 202, 194, 206, 185, 217, 199, 209, 215]
[244, 129, 168, 47, 39, 40, 45, 42, 208, 209, 50, 71, 202, 197, 206, 187, 214, 199, 209, 215]
[244, 134, 173, 50, 39, 42, 45, 42, 208, 209, 51, 80, 202, 199, 206, 189, 209, 199, 208, 217]
[243, 140, 176, 54, 39, 40, 45, 40, 209, 211, 50, 83, 205, 201, 208, 189, 205, 198, 212, 220]
[242, 142, 177, 65, 39, 42, 44, 40, 215, 212, 50, 97, 201, 203, 206, 189, 203, 200, 211, 220]
[241, 147, 182, 74, 39, 42, 44, 41, 212, 214, 51, 106, 204, 203, 209, 191, 200, 195, 209, 221]
[241, 151, 182, 78, 39, 39, 45, 42, 212, 214, 51, 108, 206, 203, 206, 192, 197, 194, 206, 220]
[246, 99, 159, 46, 38, 41, 46, 41, 197, 213, 50, 54, 199, 203, 202, 182, 222, 197, 200, 213]
[239, 151, 183, 81, 37, 42, 45, 40, 212, 211, 50, 112, 206, 203, 206, 191, 194, 197, 209, 220]
[238, 149, 185, 78, 41, 41, 47, 41, 211, 211, 51, 111, 207, 204, 206, 192, 192, 195, 207, 220]
[238, 147, 182, 74, 39, 39, 45, 44, 211, 211, 51, 107, 209, 206, 207, 192, 195, 194, 207, 221]
[241, 146, 183, 73, 39, 41, 45, 44, 212, 211, 51, 107, 208, 206, 206, 191, 197, 195, 209, 221]
[237, 147, 182, 80, 41, 41, 45, 44, 210, 212, 51, 108, 209, 209, 209, 195, 195, 197, 210, 221]
[240, 150, 183, 85, 41, 42, 45, 42, 210, 213, 53, 112, 210, 207, 209, 194, 197, 195, 209, 220]
[241, 150, 180, 83, 36, 44, 45, 40, 210, 213, 51, 112, 207, 204, 207, 192, 195, 192, 207, 219]
[239, 149, 180, 83, 42, 42, 46, 42, 210, 213, 51, 109, 209, 204, 209, 192, 198, 190, 209, 221]
[239, 149, 183, 84, 40, 42, 46, 40, 208, 213, 51, 111, 210, 204, 208, 192, 198, 187, 208, 219]
[238, 151, 184, 87, 40, 42, 43, 43, 208, 213, 51, 113, 213, 205, 208, 190, 195, 190, 208, 220]
[246, 99, 158, 44, 38, 40, 44, 41, 196, 213, 54, 55, 199, 205, 200, 182, 220, 196, 200, 213]
[246, 98, 156, 46, 40, 41, 47, 44, 197, 214, 51, 55, 199, 210, 202, 184, 220, 196, 199, 211]
[245, 96, 158, 44, 40, 41, 46, 43, 194, 213, 54, 55, 202, 205, 202, 187, 220, 199, 202, 210]
[244, 92, 157, 44, 38, 40, 46, 41, 191, 213, 51, 54, 199, 205, 205, 187, 219, 198, 202, 208]
[244, 92, 157, 46, 38, 40, 44, 44, 191, 213, 51, 54, 198, 205, 207, 188, 219, 199, 202, 208]
```

These results are comming from features extracted from my images, not sure if its relevant though, but here's my actual code:

```
for img1 in imgs1:
    img_feats = []
    for coords in coord_list:
        std_vec = np.std(img_feats[0])
        img_feats.append(img1[coords[0], coords[1]]) # extracts the features that composes my matrix
    print(img_feats)
```

The output should look like this [1.879 3.0284 5.9333 2.0156 2.2467 2.0092 4.7983 4.3554 3.6372 1.3159 2.6174 2.2336 0.9625 5.6285 5.4040 2.7887 0 3.4632 0 2.7370]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like most numpy functions, the `std` function has an `axis` parameter. `np.std(img_feats, axis=0)` will return the standard deviation of each column. `axis=1` will give the standard deviation across of each row.

In your example this would read:

```py
feat_vec_1 = []
for img1 in imgs1:
    img_feats = []
    for coords in coord_list:
        img_feats.append(img1[coords[0], coords[1]])
    feat_vec_1.append(img_feats) 

std_colomns = np.std(feat_vec_1, axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are really asking, but if your array is `foo`, then

```
np.std(foo, axis=0)
```

Will compute the standard deviations of all the columns.

Comment: I already tried like this, the outputs are wrong, i don't know what calculation it does, but the output is: 

76.55538844522964. If i calculate manually the output is much smaller: 1.879, which looks a lot more convincing

Comment: @JohnJones I am not sure what you mean. This will produce a vector of values. When I do it with your data, I get: `array([ 2.74145947, 19.73690959,  9.05452373, 14.31906422,  1.29938447,
        1.25155903,  1.28825463,  1.3892444 ,  6.96402183,  1.28062485,
        1.00079968, 22.19719802,  4.04618339,  4.90713766,  2.9       ,
        3.21552484,  9.86914383,  3.59827737,  3.01337021,  4.96310387])`

Comment: You've transposed your array somewhere along the line... 76.555 etc is std of the rows in your matrix in the question. If you don't change the reading of the matrix, then using `axis=1` will give the correct answer

Comment: @JohnJones However WITHOUT the `axis=0` I get `75.01260266781843`

Comment: The reason why it looks different, it's because i tested this on img_feats, and img_feats outputs the matrix in the format i showed in the picture, when i append it to feature_vector i get an array like [[el1, el2, el3, el4, el5, el6]], i upvoted your answer, because its a good answer

Comment: @IgorRivin as a matter of fact, i think yours is the right answer, could you kindly show me how you did it, please? i must confirm

Comment: @JohnJones I did it exactly as I say in the answer. I am not sure I understand the question...

Comment: Sorry, lol you were right from the beginning thats all, i just didn't understand what you meant initially, but thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
for img1 in imgs1:
    img_feats = []
    for coords in coord_list:
        std_vec = np.std(img_feats[0])
        img_feats.append(img1[coords[0], coords[1]])
    feat_vec_1.append(img_feats) 
    print(img_feats)
```

I don't get this actually, maybe you should calculate the deviation after you built the whole matrix? And the column you get with `img_feats[0,:]` if it is a numpy array